# REST returning lists , conflicting sources

Tags: rest

So my company started introducing REST api last year. We took some time researching REST to understand it as best as we could (was a long complicated book), and thus we went onto writing our rest api.

Everything went fine, we changed developers and I find myself lead dev.

We got a new developer who has never done REST and instinctively he wrote a rest service that returned a list of objects within an object.

This lead me to read more about it as previously I had been lead to believe this was the wrong approach. Now there are different sources telling me different things.

I will use examples:

GET /users returns a list of URI's (that fit the uri below).

GET /users/{id} returns that specific user.

The original book said we should not return a list of objects. We have been looping around the list of uri's to get our list of users for example. This is also suggested on wikipedia.

I have read in other places (like here on stack), that returning an array of objects is fine. Now I am looking back and thinking "what have we been doing?".

Any enlightenment would be fantastic thanks.

Comment: do you mean, you should return the objects or not?

Comment: @FranckV It does not address the other side of the argument, the sources that say it should return a list of uri's, not objects.

Comment: @Salman Yea Should it return a list of uri's to the individual objects e.g. "/user/1. /user/2" etc, or the objects themselves. I originally read it should be the uri's and not a list of objects.

Comment: GET /users would return the entire collection, meaning an array of all the objects [{},{}]
GET /users/{id} would return a single object {}

Comment: @FranckV I am very confused why some sources say otherwise. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_state_transfer